# Why is cosine similarity always counted as 1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, cosine-similarity

While working on a school project, there was a problem that the cosine similarity was always measured as 1. I had no choice but to question that the cosine similarity was always measured as 1 because I confirmed that the tensor1 and tensor2 were different. Why is the cosine similarity always measured as 1?

1. training code

```
for i, (_image1, _label1) in enumerate(train_loader):
    image1 = _image1.to(DEVICE)
    label1 = _label1[0]
    vector1_tensor = model(image1)
  
    if (i == 0): #Exception Case
      image2 = image1
      label2 = label1
      vector2_tensor = vector1_tensor
   
     #PROBLEM LOCATION 

     similarity =  F.cosine_similarity(vector1_tensor, vector2_tensor, dim = -1)
     scaled_similarity = torch.sigmoid(similarity)

    if label1 == label2:
      target_vector = [1]
    else :
      target_vector = [0]

    target_tensor = torch.tensor(target_vector).float()
    target_tensor = target_tensor.to(DEVICE)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    cost = loss(scaled_similarity, target_tensor)
    cost.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if not i % 40:
      print (f'Epoch: {epoch:03d}/{EPOCH:03d} | '
            f'Batch {i:03d}/{len(train_loader):03d} |'
             f' Cost: {cost:.4f}')

    #Recycle tensor for reduced computation
    image2 = image1.clone()
    label2 = label1
    vector2_tensor = vector1_tensor.detach()
```

2. model define code

```
class trans_VGG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, base_dim):
        super(trans_VGG, self).__init__()
        self.feature = nn.Sequential(
            conv_2(3, base_dim),
            conv_2(base_dim, base_dim*2),
            conv_2(base_dim*2, base_dim*4),
            conv_3(base_dim*4, base_dim*8),
            conv_3(base_dim*8, base_dim*8)
        )
        self.fc_layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(base_dim*8*7*7, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(4096, 1000),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(1000, 800)
        )
        for param in self.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.feature(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc_layer(x)
        return x
```

1. Instead of using Pytorch's cosine similarity function, we created and calculated the cosine similarity function ourselves and found that the cosine similarity was still 1.
2. We found that the values of sensor1 and sensor2 are different.
3. This model is a VGG model, which obtains the similarity between the two tensors by embedding the two tensors that passed through the VGG model.

Comment: Can you share the shapes of `vector1_tensor`, `vector2_tensor` and the values that `i` actually takes?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the code you posted. I suggest you create a [mre], three lines of code that define the two vectors and compute the cosine similarity. Then we have something to talk about.

Comment: I took your advice and modified the post. I will try to write better in the future by referring to the link you attached. However, the problem has changed. Now, cosine similarity is output normally in the training code. However, cosine similarity is still output as 1 in the accounting and loss function. This problem occurs even though I used the same dataset as the training code. Why is that?

For your information, tensor1 and tensor2 are vectors that this vgg model returns.

Answer (score 0):

Cosine similarity measures the angle between vectors. Vectors that have different magnitudes but still point in the same direction will have a cosine similarity of 1.